# How to get jasmine tests to load data and execute in the right order

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I'm using Jasmine (2.3.2) and Protractor (2.5.1) for my UI tests. I need to load in data and generate tests for each item from that array. I have a function (`checkItem`) that creates a new `describe` function for each item and checks certain properties on that object. This is a very simplified version of my code and there are other tests that run before these.

If I call `checkItem` in a `describe` statement, `itemsArr` isn't defined yet. So I'm not sure how to get the data loaded and create dynamic tests from that data.

```
var data = require('get-data'); //custom module here

describe('Test', function() {
  var itemsArr;
  beforeAll(function(done) { 
    data.get(function(err, result) {
      itemsArr = result; //load data from module
      done();
    });
  })

  //error: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
  describe('check each item', function() {
    itemsArr.forEach(function(item) {
      checkItem(item);
    });
  });

  function checkItem (item) {
    var itemName = item.name;
    describe(itemName, function() {
      console.log('describe');
      //this doesn't fire when 'should check item' is called
      it('should work', function() {
        console.log('it');
        expect(false).toBeTruthy();
      });
    });
  }

});
```

**UPDATE**: When I change my code like this it's the same issue, so maybe there's another way to load data instead of using `beforeAll`/`beforeEach`

```
beforeAll(function() {
  itemsArr = [
    {
      name: 'apple'
    },
    {
      name: 'orange'
    },
    {
      name: 'banana'
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Not necessarily an answer, but if you can forgo loading the data via AJAX, you could look into [Jasmine Data-Driven Tests](https://github.com/gburghardt/jasmine-data_driven_tests). It currently doesn't work in NodeJS, but the basic premise is very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an undefined `itemsArr` cause the code in the inner `describe` executes very early in the process and before the `beforeAll` finishes getting the data. Having `it` in place of `describe` would let it wait for `beforeAll` to finish.

The problem with `it` now is that you cannot have nested `it`s - jasmine would not execute the inner its, see [this relevant issue](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/830).

If you would not create inner `it`s dynamically, but just make your expectations in the parent `it` - this is going to work. Working sample:

```
describe('Test', function() {
    var itemsArr;
    beforeAll(function(done) {
        itemsArr = [
            {
                name: 'apple'
            },
            {
                name: 'orange'
            },
            {
                name: 'banana'
            }
        ];
        done();
    });

    it('should check each item', function() {
        itemsArr.forEach(function(item) {
            expect(false).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });

});
```

It produces 3 `Expected false to be truthy` failures.

---

I still think that if we would try using *Protractor's Control Flow*, we might have a better solution.

Comment: @cocoa okay, correct me if I'm wrong - this happens even if `itemsArr` is inside the `describe('Check item', function() {`? Thanks.

Comment: yes, if i do `describe('check item', function() {
    itemsArr.forEach(function(item) {
      checkItem(item);
    });
  })`

Comment: @cocoa okay, just to make sure - this is jasmine2 you are using, correct?  Could you please also check if temporarily replacing `beforeAll` with `beforeEach` makes any difference? Thanks.

Comment: @cocoa okay, updated the answer with my view of the problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, that seems like the best way to go